# How can I draw a line with easeljs-0.8.0.js?(createJs)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

guys. I use easeljs-0.8.0.js to draw a line, but it doesn't work, can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="lib/easeljs-0.8.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="demoCanvas" width="1200" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("demoCanvas");
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    var lineShape = new createjs.Shape();
    lineShape.graphics.moveTo(10,10).setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke("#ff0000").lineTo(50,50);
    stage.addChild(lineShape);
    stage.update();
}
</script>
</html>
```

I can't draw a line with the code above!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.8.0 the Graphics engine was rewritten, and you now need to call `moveTo` after `beginStroke`, `beginFill`, or `beginStrokeStyle`, as these methods "reset" the path.

See: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/520

Comment: Thank you, I got it. If possible, I hope the createJs tutorials could be clearer.

Comment: Another question, how should I create a responsive canvas with createJs?I want to develop a html5 mobile game. As you know, the screens of mobile devices are different size, so I want to create a responsive canvas so that it can adapt different screen?

Comment: @JospehusChou You can change the width and height values of the canvas when the browser resizes. Add a resize event handler on the window and update your canvas accordingly.


<code>
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

function handleResize(event) {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
</code>

Comment: Same with v0.8.2. Thanks for pointing out. Just to give the right line of code for the OP: `lineShape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1).beginStroke("#ff0000").moveTo(10,10).lineTo(50,50).endStroke();` which draws a line. I have added endStroke()